# pattern to proxy (different) methods to many different classes

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a **bunch** of classes with a unique set of methods.

```
class1 {
    method1(dbconn, args...);
    method2(dbconn, args...);
}

class2 {
    method3(dbconn, args...);
    method4(dbconn, args...);
}

class3 {
    method5(dbconn, args...);
}
```

We need to expose all the methods via a flat library:

```
class library {
    init () {
        //create instance of all helper classes
    }
    method1(args...) {
        return class1Instance.method1(getDbconn(), args...);
    }
    method2(args...) {
        return class1Instance.method2(getDbconn(), args...);
    }
    method3(args...) {
        return class2Instance.method3(getDbconn(), args...);
    }
    method4(args...) {
        return class2Instance.method4(getDbconn(), args...);
    }
    method5(args...) {
        return class3Instance.method5(getDbconn(), args...);
    }
}
```

But it is very time consuming, and there is a lot of repetitive code to move each method into the library. Is there a better way to do this?

Note that each method name is unique. The arguments and return value are of different types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define an interface:

```
interface library {
    method1();
    ...
    methodN();
}
```

then use dynamic proxy to reflectively invoke methods of your service implementations. you will also have to find a solution on how to choose on which service particular method should be invoked. but this is not very hard.

you can implement a class:

```
class ServiceDemultiplexer implements InvocationHandler {

     ServiceDemultiplexer(Object services[]) {
       ... 
     }

     public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args)
    throws Throwable
     {
        ...
     }
}
```

Comment: I think yours is the best answer to the problem. Thanks. However I have half a mind to write code to autogenerate the library class - that would avoid the performance hit of the dynamic proxy and the demultiplexing function.

Comment: What is the advantage of this solution?

Answer (score 0):

The better way of doing it it to avoid doing it.

A class should have a well-defined, as coherent as possible, set of responsibilities. If all these classes exist, it's certainly because each one has a different set of responsibilities than the other ones. Why don't you let the caller choose the appropriate class to use and call the appropriate method from this class.

You could use your `Library` class as a factory of helper classes. The callers would just have to do

```
library.getClass1().method1(...);
```

If you guive it real names, it becomes more natural:

```
library.getProductManager().createProduct();
```

But even then, injecting the specific dependencies to caller object looks better to me than relying on a huge factory like this. Use a dependency injection framework like Spring or Guice.

Comment: @Nizet:I think the aim is to make a `Facade` pattern.It seems that the expectation is to have a uniform interface for the clients while the implementation under the hood will delegate to the appropriate objects (e.g. class1 or class2).

Comment: Yes, that's also what I have understood. But having several facades with well-defined responsibilities is better than having such a gigantic do-it-all facade.

Comment: @JBNizet Agreed. I would also rather not do it this way. However the library is used by a web service, which has all its methods listed in a very flat format. And our requirement is to make the web service and library have the exact same interface.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are working on and if using reflection is not an issue, you might call everything through a dynamic proxy.

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2000/jw-1110-proxy.html

Your *InvocationHandler.invoke* would just locate class and method declaring *Method m* in its parameter, instantiate an object of that class (could be done sooner than that too) and pass the call to it. The actual implementation depends on what you already have.